# Re-coding Select JPEG Blocks with Pillow / PIL

Tags: jpeg, python-imaging-library

Is there someway in PIL / Pillow to open a JPEG file, modify a portion of the image and then save the image back to JPEG where only the blocks with modifications are re-encoded?

There are libraries with support for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Lossless_editing

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is impossible. JPEG encodes in groups called MCUs that are composed of one or more 8x8 data blocks. You'd have to encode along the data block or MCU boundary.

The other problem is that DC coefficients (the [0,0] coefficient from the DC) are encoded together. Changing one means you need to change all the ones that follow.

Comment: This is the technique that I am referring to: http://www.betterjpeg.com/jpeg-plug-in.htm.

Comment: They would have to be doing some touching of the other blocks. You could get pretty much the same effect by using the same quantization tables and sampling when you recompress.

Comment: 1. Yes you can just use the same tables. 2. JPEG allows defining multiple quantization and Huffman tables so you could modify the header and add new tables if that is optimal. Either way, not-recoding untouched blocked IS possible, so my question is: is this possible in PIL.

Comment: No, you'd read the quantization tables sampling from the source file then use them when recompressing. You can change the huffman tables without effect. You're still "recompressing" the data but with little change.